# Display result of MYSQL event scheduler in an interface

Tags: mysql

I have a database containing the name and the associated birthday. I have set an event scheduler to periodically check the database for bithdays within two days from the current date. This is my code-

```
 DELIMITER $$ CREATE EVENT `Reminder` ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 Day
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO BEGIN
select * from reminder where date_format(date_sub(Birthday,interval 2 day),'%m-%d') = Date_Format(curdate(),'%m-%d');

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Apparently the sql query does not display any information. I would like to display the result of the query in an interface, whenever the query returns at least one row.

Comment: event is a server action. YOu will have to insert the found birthday in a "reminder" table and retrieve the reminder from there. This pretty much renders your event useless. A way to make it usefull is maybe send out an e-mail when an event is found?

Comment: Apart from sending an email, can a notification be made on the desktop?

Comment: Only by using a second piece of code to retrieve the event you created from a seperate result table. However when you do that, you do not need the event anymore, you cna then just run the SQL unless you want people to be reminded that they forgot something, then an intermediate table for storing all this is useful again.